# PHP Possible to use namespaces (or anything else) to include two classes of same name

Tags: php, namespaces

I have a class named 'Users' in /v1/users.php and another class named 'users' in /v2/users.php (v1 is a legacy API to our database). I'm trying to write migration code using both APIs.

Is there a way I can use both of these classes in a migration class? I unfortunately can't declare the namespaces in the users.php files themselves, but am wondering if there's some way I can encapsulate the include itself in a namespace? For example, in migrations.php:

```
<?php
namespace v1 {
require_once("v1/users.php");
}
namespace v2 {
require_once("v2/users.php");
}

class migration
{
    public function migrateUser($v1UserId)
    {
        $v1Users = new v1\Users;
        $v2Users = new v2\users;
        $v2Users->addUser($v1Users->getUser($v1UserId));
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Does your example code not work?  It looks like it should.  Though, you'll probably need to do `new \v1\Users` and `new \v2\users`.  The leading slash makes sure PHP looks for the namespace from the root.

Comment: I'm getting `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'v1\Users' not found in migration.php on line 13`, whether I have \v1\Users or \v1\users.

Answer (score 1):

Along with  Rocket Hazmat's comment, I'm pretty sure you need a global/blank namespace for the other code as well.  Once you use the bracketed `namespace { }` syntax in a file, all code must be in a namespace:

```
namespace {
    class migration
    {
        public function migrateUser($v1UserId)
        {
            $v1Users = new \v1\Users;
            $v2Users = new \v2\users;
            $v2Users->addUser($v1Users->getUser($v1UserId));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Still getting an error though- `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'v1\Users' not found in migration.php on line 13`. The users.php file is just a class (`<?php class users { ... } ?>`)